# ftp error 501: Server cannot accept argument

Tags: iis, ftp, ftp-client, ftplib

I am using the following ftp commands to retrieve data to the local machine from the remote server but I got the error 501.

Does any way to bypass this error?

```
ftp> open xx.xxx.xxx.xx
Connected to xx.xxx.xxx.xx.
220 Microsoft FTP Service
User (xx.xxx.xxx.xx:(none)):
331 Password required

230 User logged in.
ftp> QUOTE PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (95,142,103,59,237,58).
ftp> cd \some\path\out
250 CWD command successful.
ftp> lcd \user\myfolder
Local directory now E:\user\myfolder.
ftp> binary
200 Type set to I.
ftp> get test.txt
501 Server cannot accept argument.
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection.
```